# Angular bootsrap ui , pop up an input in a modal template on focus

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

How can i make an input to pop up on focus using Angular bootsrap ui  plugin ,in my angular app ,below is my code for modal view :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 modal-body">
    <div class="form-group" ng-hide="choice.saved">
          <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" class="form-control" ng-model="choice.item_name"/>                             

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use resolve function to input data to a modal pop up

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function(size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```